# PHP connecting to database: retrieving records

Tags: php, sql

```
<?php

$dbCon2=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "dbusers")
       or die(mysql_error()."Connection disconnected");

$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM users";
$sql2 = mysqli_query($dbCon2, $sql1);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql2))
    {

    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['UserID'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Firstname'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Lastname'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Gender'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Email'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Status'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Date_joined'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }

?>
```

- I'm still getting the same error again and again. :(

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given

Comment: If any of the answers below solved your problem, please consider accepting them by clicking the outlined checkmark under your down arrow.  Doing so not only helps them, but helps you as well by awarding reputation.

Answer (score 2):

That would be because you are mixing `mysql_*` and `mysqli`... two different extensions.

It would appear you're looking for [`mysqli_fetch_array()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php).  Also, make sure to use the correct error catching.. you are currently using `mysql_error()` to fetch errors.. I'm not used to using mysqli, but that seems wrong to me.

Comment: good point, if using `mysqli_fetch_array` that will be better

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql2 = mysqli_query($dbCon2, $sql1);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql2))
```

You are mixing up your API.  `mysql_*` is different from `MySQli`

Try Running:

```
$sql2 = mysqli_query($dbCon2, $sql1);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql2, (MYSQLI_ASSOC))
```

Answer (score 0):

Change mysql_fetch_array to mysqli_fetch_array because the returned values from the mysqi_query is an object and must be passed to a mysqli_fetch_array :)